# Fix the rules in mod security

Tags: mysql, apache, mod-security

I have install  mod security 2.5.12
i got the error 403 Forbidden for some php file
So it is false positive
i want to disable the rule for this perticular warning
So can any one tell me that how can i know the rule for this error in mod security file??

Answer (score 0):

In the mod_security.log file is written the line and the rule. For example:

```
Message: Access denied with connection close (phase 2). Matched phrase "msnbot" at REQUEST_HEADERS:User-Agent. [file "/home/oscar/conf/mod_sec_default_action.conf"] [line "28"] [id "60008"]
```

You should add or modify the SecAuditEngine parameter to begin to log in httpd.conf, with the value

> SecAuditEngine   On

, or

> SecAuditEngine RelevantOnly

The rule information appears in the file you have especified in SecAuditLog in httpd.conf.

```
SecAuditLog /logs/mod_security.log
```